# how to make polymorphic constructor typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor, polymorphism

I'm trying to make a polymorphic constructor in typescript:

```
class Base {
  constructor(params: Params) {...}
  
  val = 3;

  protected create(params: Params): this {
    // return new this(params);
    return new this.constructor(params);
  }
}

class Child extends Base {
  val = 5;

  // should not be necessary
  protected create(params: Params): this {
    return new Child;
  }
}
```

This should work, for example when I run it in the browser:

```
var base = new Base();
var child = new Child();

console.log(base.create().val); // -> 3;
console.log(child.create().val); // -> 5;
```

However, typescript is not ok with this and gives this error:

```
This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'Function' has no construct signatures.ts(2351)
```

I did get around it by casting to this:

```
// in parent
protected create(params: Params) {
  return new Base(params) as this;
}

// in child
protected create(params: Params) {
  return new Child(params) as this;
}
```

I am wondering, what is the correct way to do this?